# How to before update oracle to Set Active

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I create trigger before update table periode:

```
create or replace TRIGGER peka_periode_setActive
    BEFORE UPDATE ON pekaonline_periode
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :new.SET_ACTIVE := 0;
END;
```

example table

```
id  |  SET_ACTIVE
1   |    1
2   |    0
3   |    0
52  |    0
```

Then I update row like:

```
UPDATE pekaonline_periode SET SET_ACTIVE = 1 WHERE PERIODE_ID = 52;
```

But the result all SET_ACTIVE = **`0`**

What's wrong for the triggers, it is before update. What I want ID = `52` to SET_ACTIVE `1` and another SET to `0`

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? That code wont run on both...

Comment: using oracle sql developer. I think you must create table before @jarlh

Comment: Is your actual requirement that only one record can have `setactive=1` at any given time? If so please state it explicitly. It's a lot easier for us to understand your business rules if you tell us what they are instead of expecting us to infer them from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, I understand what you want: you want to set active to current row and unset from prev active row. So, I really understand that  my code it`s not good practice, but whatever:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER peka_periode_setActive
    BEFORE UPDATE ON pekaonline_periode
    FOR EACH ROW 
declare
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
  if :new.SET_ACTIVE = 1 then
    UPDATE t1
    SET SET_ACTIVE = 0
    WHERE SET_ACTIVE = 1;

    commit;
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: In my case there is pragma autonomous_transaction;

Comment: Fair point. I tend to regard the use of `pragma autonomous_transaction` in triggers as a code smell. But I think your analysis of the OP's requirement is correct.

Comment: @APC - I didn't say that is good-write code. 
It is only quick answer for question.

*For me better use Compound trigger.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't commenting on your code. As I said I think it solves the OP's question. What I meant was, the need to have  `pragma autonomous_transaction` usually indicates a problem in the design or requirement.

Comment: @I3rutt. `Commit` in a trigger ?? I guess DML are auto commit in triggers. Isn't it ?

Comment: @XING There is autonomous_transaction, so we need commit. If we remove commit:
ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back

Comment: its work.. I dont know what means `pragma autonomous_transaction`

Comment: Normally we are not allowed to update the table which owns the trigger in the trigger code (it causes )RA-04061: mutating table error). The `pragma autonomous_transaction` opens up a separate (nested) transaction which allows us to run DML. However, we must commit the autonomous transaction. Autonomous transactions can be unsafe. For instance you might end up with no records where `setactive=1` if the main transaction fails and is rolled back whilst the nested transaction is committed.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code - trigger will always replace the column value of SET_ACTIVE to 0 before the triggering statement is run.

In simple way-

- Update Statement submitted with SET_ACTIVE column value as 1
- Before Update trigger event fired and overrides the SET_ACTIVE value
  to 0
- Update statement executed and updated SET_ACTIVE value as 0 for the affected rows

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know clearly. can you implement to the code oracle?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then when you are updating pekaonline_periode table for certain condition (When PERIODE_ID = 52) you need to SET_ACTIVE = 1 in the same table?

Then you use when clause in your trigger -

```
  BEGIN
  if :new.PERIODE_ID = 52 then
   :new.SET_ACTIVE := 1;
  end if;
  END;
```

Comment: how to know id `52` for trigger? Its not must id 52. its can change what i want. @PravinSatav see on my update question. thank

Comment: @Stfvns : Didn't understand the requirement. In your question you have mentioned that if id=52 then during update "set active" column should have value as 1 for all other cases it should be 0. You use need to add else in my answer and it will be something like :new.set_active=1